# What does "dish it back" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "retaliate"? I didn't find it here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dish

"Another tip? Don't be afraid to stop your colleagues when they are just repeating a point you've already made. Gates says she does it to her husband all the time (and he **dishes it back**, too).
"If a man is re-explaining -- or 'mansplaining' -- something a woman has done, stop them in the meeting, and say, 'That's okay, she already said that. Let's move on,'" she said."

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2017/09/19/news/melinda-gates-american-opportunity-women-poverty/index.html?iid=Lead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **dish** something **back** is slang for "to speak to someone in a manner similar to their manner when speaking to you".

If someone speaks rudely to you and you speak rudely back, you are **dishing it back** at them. Or if someone use a lot of jargon when speaking to you and you throw a bunch of jargon back at them, you're "dishing it back".

That which is "dished back" is usually tinged with some form of unpleasantness or strife. If someone praises you and you praise them back, it would be an ironic/humorous usage to say that you were "dishing it back" at them.